# bypass known exception of mysql in python

Tags: python, mysql-python

I am trying to bypass "**Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails**" inside my python script.
So I am planning to drop all tables but this error throws up due to  inter relationship.

My query is I need to get this automated and i know I am gonna come with the same error, but I know how to bypass it by calling `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;` and then once deleted enable the feature again `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;`.
Need to know how to automate this inside python

```
import MySQLdb
import sys

if len(sys.argv) != 4:
        print "please enter the Hostname to connect followed by:"
        print "mysql username;"
        print "mysql db to connect;"
else:
        _host = sys.argv[1]
        _user = sys.argv[2]
#       _pass = sys.argv[3]
        _db   = sys.argv[3]
        cham = raw_input("please enter the command to be executed:- ")
        _pass = raw_input("please enter password:- ")

        if cham == "drop table":
            db = MySQLdb.connect(host = _host, user = _user,db =  _db, passwd = _pass )
            cursor = db.cursor()
            cursor.execute("show tables")
            for i in cursor.fetchall():
                cursor.execute("drop table" + " " + (i[0]))
                print cursor.fetchall()
                print "all the tables has been deleted"
            db.close()
        else:
            db = MySQLdb.connect(host = _host, user = _user,db =  _db, passwd = _pass )
            cursor = db.cursor()
            cursor.execute(cham)
            print cursor.fetchall()
            db.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following snip and it worked, thanks anyways.

```
        if cham == "drop table":
            db = MySQLdb.connect(host = _host, user = _user,db =  _db, passwd = _pass )
            cursor = db.cursor()
            cursor.execute("show tables")
            for i in cursor.fetchall():
                try:
                    cursor.execute("drop table" + " " + (i[0]))
                    #print cursor.fetchall()
                except:
                    cursor.execute("SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0")
                    cursor.execute("drop table" + " " + (i[0]))
                    cursor.execute("SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1")
#               print "all the tables has been deleted"
            db.close()
```