# Pandas to_sql without foreign key check

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy

I have been looking a lot on the internet to find a solution but couldn't find anything interesting. So I'm asking here if there is any way to insert data with pandas without checking foreign keys or desactivate it ? I'm working on a MySQL DB and with phpmyadmin you have the possibility to uncheck 'check foreign keys'

What I tried is `df.to_sql(con=engine, name=tableName, if_exists='append', chunksize=chunksize, index= False)`

I'm trying to have this because sometime my datas aren't complete in the DB and the foreign key isn't respected once, which makes the insert crashing and the whole table will be empty 
Thanks

Comment: Have a look at [bypass known exception of mysql in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38898601/bypass-known-exception-of-mysql-in-python)

Comment: you think I can combine SQLAlchemy and MySQLDB ?

Comment: What would you need SQLAlchemy for? Did you have a look at the link? Did you understand the approach? If you have a question/remark, say so and don't talk in riddles.

Comment: Yeah i got it right and it's working, I already did that for an other part of my code and I just changed ```df.to_sql(con=engine, name=tableName, if_exists='append', chunksize=chunksize, index= False)``` to ```df.to_sql(con=conn, name=tableName, if_exists='append', chunksize=chunksize, index= False)``` and add everything from that link you gave me ;)